# Keras Custom generator issue when evaluating the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

I am training a CNN LSTM model using Keras, and after the training was done, I tried to evaluate the model on the testing data like I did when I fine-tuned my CNN, however an error appears this time.

After training was done, I tried to following piece of code to evaluate on my testing set:

```
x, y = zip(*(testgenerator[i] for i in range(len(testgenerator))))

x_test, y_test = np.vstack(x), np.vstack(y)

loss, acc = Bi_LSTM.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=9)

print("Accuracy: " ,acc)
print("Loss: ", loss)
```

I have used this code before to evaluate my fine tuned model and it had no issue, but now I get the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

I have tried few solutions online like using len(list(generator)) but it did not work. Is it because I am using a custom generator? How can I do to evaluate model in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this is by using a different method. In this case I do not need to extract values for x,y:

```
loss, acc = Bi_LSTM.evaluate_generator(testgenerator, batch_size=9)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is the problem

```
x, y = zip(*(testgenerator[i] for i in range(len(testgenerator))))
```

because you call `len` on generator object. 
The solution may be if you just create some counter, increment it and use it as index in `testgenerator[i]`

Comment: That line certainly is the problem, but I used the same code with a different model (using the Keras default datagenerator and I had no issue with it. Even if I switch to counter, I need to know the value of `len(testgenerator)` to stop the loop

Comment: Can you use gen.next() for getting the batches and when there is no more complete batches, then stop the training? Is that possible in your case?

Comment: Not really since it does not use flow_from_directory. This latter is called by the two generators inside of my custom one